# How to Remove camera flip icon in react-video-recorder?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-video-recorder for recording camera recording , but in mobile phone view its showing camera flip button and i dont want the functionality , so i want to get rid of it. can anyone please help me
I am currently passing props like these :-

```
<VideoRecorder
            isFlipped={false}
            audio={true}
            constraints={videoConstraints}
            onUserMediaError={handleError}
            ref={webcamRef}
            renderDisconnectedView={() => <div>disconnected</div>}
            onRecordingComplete={(videoBlob) => {
              setBlob(videoBlob);
              handleStopCaptureClick();
            }}
            renderLoadingView={() => <div></div>}
            renderActions={({
              t,
              isVideoInputSupported,
              isInlineRecordingSupported,
              thereWasAnError,
              isConnecting,
              isRunningCountdown,
              isReplayingVideo,
              onTurnOnCamera,
              onStopReplaying,
            }) => {
              const renderContent = () => {
                const shouldUseVideoInput =
                  !isInlineRecordingSupported && isVideoInputSupported;

                if (
                  (!isInlineRecordingSupported && !isVideoInputSupported) ||
                  thereWasAnError ||
                  isConnecting ||
                  isRunningCountdown
                ) {
                  return null;
                }

                if (isReplayingVideo) {
                  return (
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={onStopReplaying}
                      title="start-replaying"
                    >
                      {t("Use another video")}
                    </Button>
                  );
                }
                if (!shouldUseVideoInput && turnonCamera) {
                  onTurnOnCamera();
                  setturnonCamera(false);
                }
              };

              return <div>{renderContent()}</div>;
            }}
          />
```

Comment: If there is no way to do it through the component itself, maybe you can cheat it with CSS.  Is there a way you can inspect the rendered html and find the class related to the camera flip icon and hide it through CSS?

Comment: its basically appears on mobile only so its kinda hard to do that , can u pls suggest alternate way

Comment: You found any solution ?